# Controlling the color of text in an array based on a predefined condition

Tags: matlab, textcolor

I am trying to display a matrix M of size 50x8 with a plot using `text([x,y],M)`. All the entries in matrix are at present of the same color. I would like more control on the display, and would like that all matrix entries satisfying a particular condition should be of different color.

One of the possible ways to do is to specify the position for each of the elements of the matrix M individually in `text(x,y,M_ij)`. But I am only specifying the position for the first element, and other positions are being assigned automatically. How can I get those positions, or control them? This will allow me to control the colors as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resulting text graphics object is only one object, so you can't adjust the color through handle graphics without affecting all of the rows.  But if it's possible for you, you can specify the color directly in the strings.  To do this, you'll probably need to represent your strings as a cell array instead, so they can have different colors.

```
M = {'\color{red}Line 1';'\color{blue}Line 2';'\color[rgb]{.6 .8 .2}Line 3'};
text(1, 1, M);
```

The reference for other inline string markup is found on this doc page, in the 'String' property: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text_props.html

Comment: Thanks peter, it works. I am now trying to create the cell string having color and value juxtaposed.